# How to hook up access for plugin to access users cloud storage

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-oauth

I am making a plugin for users to upload to a gcloud bucket directly from vscode. This will be run in a nodejs environment on the users machine. Therefore I cannot store any secrets in the plugin.

I have enabled the storage api in Google Cloud Console. What I want is for the user to authenticate via the consent screen which then returns a key/token (which can be stored locally) that I can pass into the storage constructor so that the plugin has access to upload to that user's bucket.

Something like this:

```js
const {OAuth2Client} = require('google-auth-library');

const credentials = //get credentials from oauth library

const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');
new Storage({credentials});
```

What are the steps to do this?

Comment: I think that Cloud Storage documentation about [Authorizing request with OAuth 2.0](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/authorizing#OAuth2Authorizing) it will work for you.

Comment: @TasosV Few questions. I feel like that documentation is for the json api rather than the actual api (the one the `@google-cloud/storage` connects to)?